# perl DBI grant privileges

Tags: mysql, database, perl

Please help understand what I'm doing wrong here. I guess escaping is wrong, but I can't google a workable example.

```
my $host = "localhost";
my $port = "3306";
my $user = "root";
my $pass = "111";
my $db_name = "test";
my $db_user = "test";
my $db_pass = "test";

my $dsn = "dbi:mysql::$host:$port";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";

$dbh->do("CREATE DATABASE $db_name");
$dbh->do("CREATE USER $db_user\@$host");
$dbh->do("GRANT ALL ON $db_name.* TO $db_user\@$host IDENTIFIED BY $db_pass");

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Error:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'test'@'localhost' at /home/andrew/sandbox/script.pl line 42.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test' at line 1 at /home/andrew/sandbox/script.pl line 43.
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the password.

```
$dbh->do("GRANT ALL ON $db_name.* TO $db_user\@$host IDENTIFIED BY '$db_pass'");
                                                                   ^        ^
```

Though of course prepared statements/parameters would be much better (if MySQL allows them here, which I'm not 100% sure of).

You should quote the `$db_user` and `$host` as well (again, assuming parameters don't work).

If parameters work:

```
$dbh->do(q{GRANT ALL ON ?.* TO ?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?}, {}, $db_name, $db_user, $host, $db_pass);
```

I'm fairly confident parameters will work on the password, and probably also on user and host. The database name, I'm not so sure of. You may just have to inline it with `quote_identifier`.

edit: You should just strike the `CREATE USER` line entirely. Granting permissions will create the user (and with a password).

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you, $password contains a simple string with no spaces and the error points to the 'create user' and 'grant' commands

Comment: @lush: The [GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) requires single quotes around the password. You don't have them. So you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: That worked out. Yes, quoting does not work with the user but I just commented the 'create user' string as it's not obligatory. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create the user every time you run the script -- I get that exact error if I try to create a user more than once.

Comment: You're right! I dropped the user and quoted it as '$db_user'\@'$host', now it's fully working. Thanks)